# calling java command using excel 2010 vba

Tags: java, excel, vba

I am having trouble calling a `java` command from an `excel 2010 vba`... is the syntax correct in the `vba`?  Thank you :).

**Java command**

```
C:\Program Files\BioDiscovery\ImaGene 9.0>ImaGene.exe -batch "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\Design\test_11_19_2015.bch"
```

**VBA**

```
' CALL JAVA PROGRAM USING SHELL '
Shell """C:\Program Files\BioDiscovery\ImaGene 9.0\ImaGene.exe"" -batch " _
          & XML­File­Name, vbNormalFocus
```

`XML­File­Name` is saved as a variable and is set , in this case, to `C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\Design\test_11_19_2015.bch`

Also, tried:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c cd C:\Program Files\BioDiscovery\ImaGene 9.0\ImaGene.exe"" -batch " _
          & XML­File­Name, vbNormalFocus")
```

Also tried,

```
MsgBox ("ImaGene running, please wait")

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1


wsh.Run "C:\Program Files\BioDiscovery\ImaGene 9.0\ImaGene.exe"" batch " _
          & XML-*File*-Name, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
MsgBox ("ImaGene completed")
```

but nothing seems to work.  Thank you :).

Comment: The command prompt does open, but no command line is written to it.  Thank you :).

Comment: I am going to close this post and open a new one as hopefully the details are a bit more clear.  Thank you :).